# Buffer.BlockCopy vs unsafe byte* pointer copy

Tags: c#, .net, performance

which one has better performance when copy a block of byte?

Comment: What does a profiler output when you test it?

Comment: @dtb, no i didn't profile it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Buffer.BlockCopy` is pretty optimised - it is basically a wrapper over a raw mem-copy; so it should be pretty fast (and avoids messing with pointers and `unsafe` code). It should be the default. You could of course measure it each way...

Comment: It's more of a mem-move, in terms of its contract, as it also handles overlapping arrays.

Answer (score 4):

*Handling of Large Byte Arrays* at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Large_Byte_Array_handling.aspx documents performance versus various methods, include the methods in your question.